# Replace all characters of a string with their variable

Tags: python

I want to replace all characters of a string of letters with a variable whos name is the same. For example strng.replace("a", a) but with all letters at the same time. How can i do this?

Comment: sounds interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the individual varibles to a dictionary and iterate through that

```
a = 10
b = 2
c = 53

P = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c}

string = 'cab'

string = list(string)
for i in range(len(string)):
    string[i] = str(P[string[i]])
string = "".join(string)
```

Comment: I get: `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: my bad, i think i fixed it now

Comment: you can loop through the items in `P` instead of length of `string`. and them inside the loop: string.replace(P[i], str(P[P[i]))

Answer (score 0):

```
dic = { 'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': 53 }
string = 'cabbaca'
res = ""

for letter in string:
    res += str(dic[letter])

print(res) # 531022105310
```

```
dic = { 'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': 53 }
string = 'cabbaca'

res = [dic[letter] for letter in string ]

print(res) # [53, 10, 2, 2, 10, 53, 10]
```